# How to enforce unique constraint between multiple columns?

Tags: database, postgresql

I currently have a problem similar to this. I am trying to create a table to store information about fathers.

Assume all fathers have two sons and that all fathers will always exist having two children, no more, no less.

```
Father_Table

father_id   |   son1_id    |    son2_id   |   father_text_info
--------------------------------------------------------------
    13      |      8       |      11      |    "some info..."


Son_Table

   son_id   |     name       
----------------------------
    8       |     Moris
```

I have not simply added Son_Table information into Father_Table because there are other tables that Son_Table will interact with.

My question is, how do I CREATE TABLE to ensure that a son1_id or son2_id cannot be entered on Father_Table if it already exists on Father_Table?

I have already tried the following:

```
CREATE TABLE father_table (
  father_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  son1_id integer NOT NULL,
  son2_id integer NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (son1_id) REFERENCES Son_Table (son_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (son2_id) REFERENCES Son_Table (son_id),
  UNIQUE (son1_id, son2_id),
  UNIQUE (son2_id, son1_id),
  UNIQUE (son1_id),
  UNIQUE (son2_id)
)
```

However the below input with duplicate Son_Table Id's is still permitted:

```
father_id   |   son1_id    |    son2_id   |   father_text_info
--------------------------------------------------------------
    13      |      8       |      11      |    "some info..."
--------------------------------------------------------------
    14      |      11      |       8      |    "other info..."
```

Comment: First off your schema is bad and denormalized. Second if a gun was to your head and you had to use that schema, then use triggers

Comment: `serial` is PostgreSQL syntax. Please remove the [mysql] tag.

Comment: One idea is to reverse the logic and ALWAYS have both rows. Reciprocation often works this way.

Comment: I'm definitely interested in better understanding how/why I would normalize. My thinking was, assuming the above conditions about father-son relationships, there is a one-to-one relation between a single father and two sons (a Father_Table row will never be inserted without two unique FK son_ids). If I had to update information about a particular son, I would simply update the Son_Table. If I had to find which 2 sons belong to a father, I would simply SELECT son1_Id, son2_id FROM Father_Table where father_id=14. If I delete sonid8, I would also DELETE FROM FatherTable WHERE s1_id=8 OR s2_id=8.

Comment: If I create a junction table for father_son which would hold father_ids and corresponding son_ids, then I am able to implement a unique constraint on the son_ids column such that no two fathers will ever relate to the same son. But the table still allows me, unfortunately, to insert more than 2 son_ids for a given father_id. `:(`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I agree with others here that `son1_id`, `son2_id` is bad design, here is an index that will forbid duplicates:

```
create extension intarray;
create unique index idx_two_sons on father_table (sort(ARRAY[son1_id, son2_id]));
```

If you combine that with a `UNIQUE` constraint on just `son1_id` and another on just `son2_id`, it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are right.  Normaliation is the answer.  Even with the advanced capabilities of PostgreSQL I cannot find a way of making this foolproof without normalizing the table (or creating a normalized tracking one with a trigger).

The problem is you can easily pick out the min and max son ids.  However you cannot cover all cases in set operations without pretty horrible performance problems.

Either break out father_to_son_id as a separate table, or maintain such a table using triggers.  Then a simple unique index will do he trick.